# AuthorizationException: User not allowed to impersonate User

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, beeline

I wrote a spark job which registers a temp table
and when I expose it via beeline (JDBC client)

```
$ ./bin/beeline
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://IP:10003 -n ram -p xxxx
0: jdbc:hive2://IP> show tables;
+---------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+
|                    tableName                          | isTemporary  |
+---------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+
| f238                                                        | true              |
+---------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------------+
2 rows selected (0.309 seconds)
0: jdbc:hive2://IP>
```

I can view the table. When querying I get this error message

```
0: jdbc:hive2://IP> select * from f238;
Error: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: ram is not allowed to impersonate ram (state=,code=0)
0: jdbc:hive2://IP>
```

I have this in hive-site.xml,

```
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.sasl.enabled</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>If true, the metastore Thrift interface will be secured with SASL. Clients must authenticate with Kerberos.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
  <value>NONE</value>
</property>
```

I have this in core-site.xml,

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
```

full log

```
ERROR [pool-19-thread-2] thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Error running hive query:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: ram is not allowed to impersonate ram
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.runInternal(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:259)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1$$anon$2.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:171)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation$$anon$1.run(SparkExecuteStatementOperation.scala:182)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea what configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
<property>
 <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Also if you want user ABC to impersonate all(*), add below properties to your core-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.ABC.groups</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>hadoop.proxyuser.ABC.hosts</name>
 <value>*</value>
</property>
```

Comment: You may accept this as Answer, upvote. Can be helpful to others

Comment: @bat_rock do you know if any other solution for this issue? We did here what you suggest but didn't work yet.

Comment: Can you send the full log

Comment: One key item to remember is that the configuration files that are adjusted MUST be copied to ALL of the nodes in your cluster or the error in question will keep occurring.

Comment: this solution works. In my case i needed to combine question's and answer's configuration

Comment: which file you add these, <property>
 <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>

Comment: I have the first set of xml snippet in my hive-site.xml file, the next set of snippet in my core-site.xml, I still that the enporsantion error, any thing I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

check that the owner of hiveserver2 process is 'hive'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).