# beeline hive jdbc connection - User: user is not allowed to impersonate hiveuser

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, beeline

hiveserver2 is up and running and I can check it from http://localhost:10002/hiveserver2.jsp.
hive is also running.
after starting beeline `>beeline` i want to connect to hive JDBC through beeline:

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default
```

`hiveuser` and `hivepassword` are configured on hive-site.xml also the same in beeline-site.xml
i've got this error:

```
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationExce
ption): User: user is not allowed to impersonate hiveuser (state=08S01,code=0)
```

This is hive-site.xml content

```
<configuration>



        <property>
            <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>hive.server2.thrift.min.worker.threads</name>
            <value>5</value>
            <description>Minimum number of worker threads</description>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>hive.server2.thrift.max.worker.threads</name>
            <value>500</value>
            <description>Maximum number of worker threads</description>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>hiveconf hive.root.logger</name>
            <value>INFO</value>
        </property> 

        <property>
            <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>


        <property>
            <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
            <value>10000</value>
            <description>TCP port number to listen on</description>
        </property>


        <property>
            <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
            <value>NONE</value>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
            <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
        </property>

        <property>

            <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
            <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
            <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
            <value>hiveuser</value>
            <description>user name for connecting to mysql server </description>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
            <value>hivepassword</value>
            <description>password for connecting to mysql server </description>
        </property> 

        <property>
            <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
            <value>/usr/hive/warehouse</value>
            <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hiveuser.hosts</name>
            <value>*</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hiveuser.groups</name>
            <value>*</value>
        </property>
```

I'm missing something or what's the solution?

Comment: Looks like you need to become the hive user, then run beeline

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: `sudo su - hive`

Comment: Or you could search for that error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909002/authorizationexception-user-not-allowed-to-impersonate-user

Comment: I followed  suggestions but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Please show your Hive xml config

Comment: I'm sorry i put it as answer it is so long if I paste it in as a comment

Comment: do you mean hive-site.xml by hive xml config ?

Comment: Please delete the answer below and [edit] your question